# ElasticSearch can't automatically recover after a big HEAP utilization

Tags: memory-management, elasticsearch

I want to talk about a problem that we are facing with our ES cluster.

Today we have four machines in our cluster, each machine has 16GB of RAM (8GB HEAP and 8GB OS).
We have a total of 73,975,578 documents, 998 shards and 127 indices.
To index our docs we use the bulk API. Today our bulk request is made with a total
up to 300 items. We put our docs in a queue so we can make the request in the background.
The log below shows a piece of the information about the amount of documents that was
sent for ES to index:

```
[2014-12-03 11:19:32 -0200] execute Event Create with 77 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:19:32 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 67
[2014-12-03 11:19:40 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:19:49 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 62
[2014-12-03 11:19:50 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 27
[2014-12-03 11:19:50 -0200] execute User Create with 2 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:19:54 -0200] execute User Create with 5 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:19:58 -0200] execute User Update with 61 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:20:02 -0200] execute User Create with 2 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:20:02 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 27
[2014-12-03 11:20:10 -0200] execute User Create with 2 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:20:19 -0200] execute User Create with 5 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:20:20 -0200] execute User Create with 3 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:20:20 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 24
[2014-12-03 11:20:25 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:20:28 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:20:37 -0200] execute Event Create with 91 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:20:42 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 76
[2014-12-03 11:20:42 -0200] execute Event Create with 300 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:20:50 -0200] execute User Create with 4 items in app 61
[2014-12-03 11:20:51 -0200] execute User Create with 1 items in app 62
[2014-12-03 11:20:51 -0200] execute User Create with 2 items in app 20
[2014-12-03 11:20:55 -0200] execute User Create with 3 items in app 61
```

Sometimes the request occurs with just one item in the bulk. Another interesting
thing is: we send that data frequently, in other words, the stress we put in
ES is pretty high.

The big problem is when ES HEAP start approaching 75% of utilization and the GC does not reach its normal value.

This log entrance show some GC working:

```
[2014-12-02 21:28:04,766][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es-node-2] [gc][old][43249][56] duration [48s], collections [2]/[48.2s], total [48s]/[17.9m], memory [8.2gb]->[8.3gb]/[8.3gb], all_pools {[young] [199.6mb]->[199.6mb]/[199.6mb]}{[survivor] [14.1mb]->[18.9mb]/[24.9mb]}{[old] [8gb]->[8gb]/[8gb]}
[2014-12-02 21:28:33,120][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es-node-2] [gc][old][43250][57] duration [28.3s], collections [1]/[28.3s], total [28.3s]/[18.4m], memory [8.3gb]->[8.3gb]/[8.3gb], all_pools {[young] [199.6mb]->[199.6mb]/[199.6mb]}{[survivor] [18.9mb]->[17.5mb]/[24.9mb]}{[old] [8gb]->[8gb]/[8gb]}
[2014-12-02 21:29:21,222][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es-node-2] [gc][old][43251][59] duration [47.9s], collections [2]/[48.1s], total [47.9s]/[19.2m], memory [8.3gb]->[8.3gb]/[8.3gb], all_pools {[young] [199.6mb]->[199.6mb]/[199.6mb]}{[survivor] [17.5mb]->[21.2mb]/[24.9mb]}{[old] [8gb]->[8gb]/[8gb]}
[2014-12-02 21:30:08,916][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es-node-2] [gc][old][43252][61] duration [47.5s], collections [2]/[47.6s], total [47.5s]/[20m], memory [8.3gb]->[8.3gb]/[8.3gb], all_pools {[young] [199.6mb]->[199.6mb]/[199.6mb]}{[survivor] [21.2mb]->[20.8mb]/[24.9mb]}{[old] [8gb]->[8gb]/[8gb]}
[2014-12-02 21:30:56,208][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es-node-2] [gc][old][43253][63] duration [47.1s], collections [2]/[47.2s], total [47.1s]/[20.7m], memory [8.3gb]->[8.3gb]/[8.3gb], all_pools {[young] [199.6mb]->[199.6mb]/[199.6mb]}{[survivor] [20.8mb]->[24.8mb]/[24.9mb]}{[old] [8gb]->[8gb]/[8gb]}
[2014-12-02 21:32:07,013][WARN ][transport                ] [es-node-2] Received response for a request that has timed out, sent [165744ms] ago, timed out [8ms] ago, action [discovery/zen/fd/ping], node [[es-node-1][sXwCdIhSRZKq7xZ6TAQiBg][localhost][inet[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9300]]], id [3002106]
[2014-12-02 21:36:41,880][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [es-node-2] [gc][old][43254][78] duration [5.7m], collections [15]/[5.7m], total [5.7m]/[26.5m], memory [8.3gb]->[8.3gb]/[8.3gb], all_pools {[young] [199.6mb]->[199.6mb]/[199.6mb]}{[survivor] [24.8mb]->[24.4mb]/[24.9mb]}{[old] [8gb]->[8gb]/[8gb]}
```

Another part that we use a lot is the ES search, these lines show some log entrances that
were generated when the search was done

```
[2014-12-03 11:43:22 -0200] buscou pagina 1 de 111235 (10 por pagina) do app 61
[2014-12-03 11:44:12 -0200] buscou pagina 1 de 30628 (10 por pagina) do app 5
[2014-12-03 11:44:13 -0200] buscou pagina 1 de 30628 (10 por pagina) do app 5
[2014-12-03 11:44:24 -0200] buscou pagina 1 de 63013 (10 por pagina) do app 20
[2014-12-03 11:44:24 -0200] buscou pagina 1 de 63013 (10 por pagina) do app 20
[2014-12-03 11:44:24 -0200] buscou pagina 1 de 63013 (10 por pagina) do app 20
```

These links show some screenshots that were taken to show some cluster information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We have already optimized some parts, the configuration of our machines is:

```
threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 30
threadpool.index.queue_size: 1000
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 30
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1000
threadpool.search.type: fixed
threadpool.search.size: 100
threadpool.search.queue_size: 200
threadpool.get.type: fixed
threadpool.get.size: 100
threadpool.get.queue_size: 200
index.merge.policy.max_merged_segment: 2g
index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier: 5
index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once: 5
index.cache.field.type: soft
index.cache.field.expire: 1m
index.refresh_interval: 60s
bootstrap.mlockall: true
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: '15%'
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
```

Our initial index process flows without any problem, the problems start to happen after some days
of usage. Sometimes the cluster stays allright during 4 or 5 days and then it shows some problems with
HEAP utilization. Are we missing any configuration or optimization?

Comment: I don't understand the title of your post. It doesn't seem to match with your description. What is the problem? Also, please bear in mind that bulk requests do require memory and the size of a bulk needs to be set according to your system limits. Is not about the number of docs you are sending in bulk but their actual physical size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrei! Actually the title indicate that when a machine in the cluster can't recovery from a big heap utilization (the GC can't run in time), all the cluster suffer.

Yes, i do know that the physical size matters.

I decrease the number of threads in each machine and it seems that the cluster is more stable now.

I will continue monitoring the cluster and let you know if something happens.

Comment: For your reference, this is what ES team recommends: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big